# Why is my AVPlayer not working?

Tags: ios, aes, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am having trouble with connecting to a live stream which is connected through HLS with 128-bit encryption, it is an Azure Media stream. The server also requires an authorization token, which is given through the HTTP header `Authorization` and is of the type `Bearer <insert token here>`.

The code I have is this:

```
let url = "http://<redacted>"

let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer <token redacted>"]
let options = ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headers]

let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: url)!, options: options)
let avItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: avItem)

player.play()
```

I have debugged the network calls and the `AVPlayer` sends out 2 calls, one to see if there is a new version (I guess from the 304 I receive on that call) and one to get the stream. These calls return with 304 Not Modified and then 206 Partial Content, respectively.

These calls:

[image: 304 call]

[image: 206 call]

I don't hear any sound, but any other sounds on the device are muted (as it should). This tells me that there is a problem with the playing of the received data. My colleague can load the stream on Android by doing nothing more than what I am doing here, and I can load it on http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html.

I check the status of the player by fetching the `player.currentItem?.status`, this is `failed`. The `player.currentItem?.error` is

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11828 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800005a610 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12847 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open}

*Edit:*  I tried debugging this further. I implemented `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` and in `resourceLoader:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:` I added the following code:

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var request = loadingRequest.request

        var headers = request.allHTTPHeaderFields!
        if headers["Authorization"] == nil {
            headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer <token>"
        } else {
            print("Auth header exists: \(headers)")
        }

        request.url = URL(string: self.url)!
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default).dataTask(with: request) {
            data, response, error in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: error)
            } else {
                loadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: data!)
                loadingRequest.finishLoading()
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    return true
}
```

I only add the `Authorization` header when it doesn't exist yet. I thought that overwriting the `Authorization` header on all calls might break the encryption.

Because `resourceLoader:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:` only gets called when the request is using a scheme other than `http` and `https`, so I replaced `http://` with `mycustomscheme://`. That is also why I set the url here, because the original url in the request does not have a valid url scheme.

This way is better for me, as I can view the request and response as they are happening. No more Burp Suite to debug the calls.

The issue I am having now is that I receive the data I expect (the player does perform the same request twice), but when I check the `player.currentItem?.status`, this is `failed`. The `player.currentItem?.error` is

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x60000005f320 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-1001 "(null)"}}

It seems weird to me that I get a timeout, as the Android and web versions work without problems.

I have looked into the Android code and he uses `<url>.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl-v3)` instead of just `<url>.ism/manifest`. If I use that url, I get the same `failed` status, but with an error of

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x608000059e60 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12936 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12936), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

Okay I got it to work, but I have no idea why it works and why it didn't work. I entered the URL that Android performs as a second call to get the stream, this one has the quality info embedded. It is of the form `<url>.ism/QualityLevels(3782)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=aac_UND_2_192)`.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: can you compare the ios/android/ampdemo http requests using an http proxy?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I have checked what the Android does and I can see that it performs 2 calls that both return 200 (one that returns a list of quality levels and another that has 50kB of Fragment(...) items), I cannot see any other calls.